# Creating scope using Property Query

Tags: search, search-scope

I'm trying to setup a search scope that uses a Property Query, but not getting the results I expect. The idea is that a specific site within my site collection has a set of pages that use taxonomy terms, and I want to create a search scope that only returns results where the page uses one of those terms.

e.g. let's say I have the following site structure

```
myserver.com/
myserver.com/support
myserver.com/support/v1
myserver.com/support/v2
myserver.com/marketing
```

I've 'tagged' all the pages in /support/v2 to use a Term Set called `Product`, which has terms of `Product OnSite`, `Product OnDemand` and `Product2`.

I'd like to create a scope that only returns results where pages in `/support/v2` have a `Product` value that includes `Product OnDemand`.

My understanding of how this should work is as follows:

1. Setup a Term Set, with Terms
2. Create a new column in the pages library for a specific site (in the example, `/support/v2`)
3. 'tag' each page within the site (`/support/v2`) to use one or more of the terms
4. within Central Admin, do a full crawl of the sitecollection
5. Create a Manager Property that maps to the crawled property `Product` (or ows_Product?)
6. Create a scope that has a rule where Type is "Property Query", Property Query is "Product" = "Product OnDemand", and behavior is "Require"

When I do the above, I get 0 items in my scope within Central Admin, and also when viewing scopes at the sitecollection level (I often see more items at the sitecollection level than in CA, even if CA shows 0 items)

It's my understanding that I'm using SharePoint 2010 Server Search, as opposed to Fast or Enterprise (i.e. ootb SharePoint 2010 Server)

Is my understanding of how this works flawed?
Are there other steps I should be taking?
Any tips on what else I can look at the make this work as expected?

Cheers

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a full crawl after adding a managed property

The first full crawl was needed to get the crawled property created such that you can create the managed property.

The second full crawl is to add data for that managed property to the property database. The values of crawled properties are not stored anywhere only the values of managed properties.

Comment: Running a second full crawl now, though I'm pretty sure I've run one twice since setting up the managed property. Would I have to run a full crawl each time I change the managed property?

Comment: I have to run another full crawl tonight, as it's possible that I didn't map the right crawled property to may managed property, but this definitely makes sense. I did also find (on my dev server) that doing a search for `Product="Product OnDemand"` did return the exact results I need, so I'm definitely on the right track ;)

Comment: So, I ran the crawl, but still my scope has no content. I retried the `Product="Product OnDemand` and still nothing. I'm starting to wonder if a consultant we engaged may have caused this inadvertently. Our 'base' web application is running on port 100 (i.e. http://myservername:100), and is then extended to port 443 so that the public can get to it. All crawling for search is done on this port 100 site, which has NTML permissions (vs. FBA for 443), so that protected content can be crawl. I wonder if this means that the scope won't work properly? clutching a straws here...

Comment: Any further advice? Full crawls did not seem to fix the issue for us.